# How to recode a variable into another variable

Tags: r, recode

I am trying to recode the following variable:

```
str(dades$Edat)
 num [1:30000] 24 26 34 37 57 37 29 23 28 35 ...
```

Into this:

```
agrupar.edat<-function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i]>=21 & x[i]<30) {x[i]<-'1'} else
      if (x[i]>=30 & x[i]<40) {x[i]<-'2'} else
        if (x[i]>=40 & x[i]<50) {x[i]<-'3'} else
          if (x[i]>=50 & x[i]<60) {x[i]<-'4'} else
            if (x[i]>=60 & x[i]<70) {x[i]<-'5'} else
        if (x[i]>=70 & x[i]<80) {x[i]<-'6'} 
  }
```

So I can put the results here:

```
edx<-agrupar.edat(dades$Edat)
```

But something is not working and edx keeps returning me "NULL"

Comment: Just use `?cut` to do this  i.e. `cut(dates$Edat, breaks = c(-Inf, -21, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80, Inf), labels = 1:6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1.**

Your function has no `return` argument.

As a result, it reads that way:

```
agrupar.edat<-function(x){
  # do stuff
  # good bye
  }
```

… so logically enough, nothing (`NULL`) comes out of it.

Try simply adding `return(1)` at the end, just before the closing bracket, and magic will happen.

Note, however, that your problem does *not* require a function. It requires…

**Problem 2.**

… using `cut`, as @akrun's comment instructs you to do.

Comment: Do you mean `return(x)`?

Comment: Nope, I did mean `return(1)`, to explain the concept. Not letting OP setting this problem up as a function :)